# Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10deb92f0>

Tags: python, django

Having issues running django site with `python3 manage.py runserver` command. When starting, I get an error below:

```
MacBook-Pro-Lev:mysite levpolomosnov$ python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors. 
<locals>.wrapper at 0x10deb92f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
return check_method()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 256, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/levpolomosnov/Documents/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
from django.urls import include, path
ImportError: cannot import name 'include'
```

Comment: Which version of django you are using?

Comment: I'm using django 2.1.4

Answer (score 2):

From django 2.0, `include` has been moved to `django.urls`. If you are using older django versions, then it might throw error. Please see the [change log form django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.0/) regarding this issue.